# SQL files management

Tags: sql, ssms

Most of my day is spent on writing SQL queries to perform small tasks, mainly to get information from the database and manipulate it somehow for data visualization building reports for others.

At the end of the day i try to have a nice folder scheme to help me reusing code and so on, but it's becoming harder to handle so many files and keep 
track of everything I've done so far. 
Don't want to have huge SQL files because I might want to 
the end It's hard to avoid a war zone in my desktop and on this folders. It's also a mess to handle so many folders/codes.

For version control we're using a GIT server, but there is plenty of code that is not in production that we would like to keep track and reuse somehow.

We're using iPython notebook, R studio and SSMS to build our codes, I'm wonder if there is some efficient ways to work.

There must be an efficient way to work out there. What do you use to keep track of your (SQL) codes? and more importantly reuse it.

Thanks in advance,
Rafael

Answer (score 0):

I just use a folder system. And I keep the shell-scripts so to speak as the first file (like the generic code to do X).  Whereas the specific codes where I take X and apply dates and other conditions in the bottom half of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

> What do you use to keep track of your (SQL) codes? and more importantly reuse it.

For ease of reuse, I have all my running SQL code backed up on an SQL server through routine INFORMATION SCHEMA dumps. For all development code that I need to reuse with others, I have a GIT server that gets automatic updates throughout the day. For reuse on my laptop itself, I have a local backup through time machine.

As for directory or folder structure, all code starts as project based and eventually I migrate the best and most useful code to a personal folder structure that is topic based (date arithmetic, indexing, etc.). No matter how they are stored, all these folders are indexed using local and remote indexing features so I can search and retrieve them with just a few keystrokes when needed. Ultimately what's needed for optimum reuse is ease of retrieval. The quicker I can retrieve, the more reuse I get.

Lastly, it's not just SQL code, but all the supporting documents that led to that code solution. Sometimes this collection may include code from other languages, code from other servers, emails, text documents, images, workflows, etc. Keeping them all together enhances the value of reuse.